# Display multiple dynamic input fields in react, based on a changing state variable?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom

So, I am building my first React app, that connects to a Flask backend. I have a specific functional component that fetches a dictionary from the Python program, and I have saved this in a state variable(done using useState, setVariables).
The object is of type

```
{'A':'x', 'B':'y', 'C':2},
```

and these are *variable*, and each render needs to be dynamic, based only on this object.
Based on the current state of this object, I want to display key-value pairs of this object in

```html
<label>insertkey</label>
<input type="text" name = "insertkey" value=insertvalue/>
```

In addition, I want to be able to save any changes made to these values, and write into the state variable, so that I can send them back to my Flask backend.

I tried looping through each, and inserting as follows:

```js
const [fields, setFields] = useState({});
//intermediate code for fetching and setting the state 

useEffect(() => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(fields)) {
    console.log(`${key}:${value}`);
    insert = insert + `<label> ${key} </label> <input type = 'text' value = ${value} name = ${key} onChange=${changedData()}></input><br/>`
  }

  document.getElementById('fields_form').innerHTML = insert;
});
const changedData = (evt) => {
  setFields({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
  console.log(evt.target.value);
}

//some intermediate code

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={submitFunction}>
      <p id='fields_form'>

      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

But when I do this, the state is set as 'Undefined'.

I would love to hear about some ways to implement this. Maybe it's a really small fix, and I'm missing it, or perhaps there is a different approach that could be more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```js
const Form = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  const onChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    // send data or save it to local store
    api.send(values)
  };
  return (
    <form encType="multipart/form-data">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="email"
        value={value["email"]}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="subject"
        value={value["subject"]}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="body"
        value={value["body"]}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      >
      <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>
        Save
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
console.log(values);
```

It's your solution.

```js
const [fields, setFields] = useState({});
const [values, setValues] = useState({});

// some fetch logic

// happens on loading some data
// for example data structure look's like:
// fetchedData = {
//   email: 'email@placeholder'
//   subject: 'subject placeholder'
//   body: 'body placeholder'
// }
useEffect(() => {
  if (fetchedData) {
    setFields(fetchedData)
  }
}, [fetchedData]);

// happens on fields changed
useEffect(() => {
  if (fields) {
    setValues(fields)
  }
}, [fields]);


const changedData = (evt) => {
  setValues({ ...values, [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
}

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={submitFunction}>
      {Object.keys(fields).map(_ => (
        <input
          type="text"
          name={_}
          value={values[_]}
          onChange={changedData}
        />
      ))}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Actually, the onChange function is not able to pass the event at all. So it gives the 'Event.target' is undefined. The exact error is--TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'evt.target.name'). Is my function call in the onChange faulty?

Comment: i'll update my answer. Set `onChange` handler into input component.

Comment: No, so I have a dynamically created form, that is, there may be a different number of input text fields(whose values are stored as a separate state variable). That is why I am iterating through each pair, and trying to add it to the required component(see the useEffect). While doing this, the onChange is not able to pass the Event variable to the changedData function(showing undefined target). Is there a way a dynamically set form like this can have an onChange handler?

Comment: See updates in my answer. You doesn’t need to update HTML Dom tree direct. In react way you need to build it using jsx. As you can see in render method we build input fields from fields object

Comment: So the .map() thing worked beautifully! Thank you so so much for your multiple responses and code edits and super helpful suggestions! :) Made a tiny change, though, which could be helpful to the others who might be reading this. Since 'fields' in this case is an object, and .map() function works only on arrays, it throws an error. So, run the .map() on the keys of Object fields--`Object.keys(fields).map`. @Pavel thanks again, was stuck on this for ages, so grateful :)

Comment: Don’t forget to read about react virtual dom tree and why we need to build html output using jsx components. Thanks for hint a bug in `fields` object.